(UK) Does a company acquisition count as being employed by the same employer in the context of a legal visa application?
How does the law treat company acquisitions with regards to continuous employment? Example below

A company was acquired (say 2 months ago) by a larger company including employees having to sign a new employment contract, a job title and salary change as well as other terms of employment.
As part of the acquisition the continuous service would include the service at employees previous company.
Letters obtained from the company as proof of employment would start from the beginning e.g. showing acquired employees have been employed by them for the past 2 years, not 2 months.
If employees fill out any application forms should they be saying they have had continuous employment for 2 years with the same company, or only 2 months?

